# Why does this `Promise.all()` statement not wait for the promises to resolve?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, mongoose, async-await

I wrote a piece of code inside an async function that shall create four users concurrently, save them to a MongoDB and print a message when this is done:

```
// Concurrently create dummy users
const dummyUserDict = [
    "name1",
    "name2",
    "name3",
    "name4"
];
const dummyUserPromises = dummyUserDict.map(async (name) => {
    let user = new User({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        username: name
    });
    return user
        .save()
        .then((result) => {
            console.log('Created user ' + result.username + '!');
        });
});

try {
    await Promise.all[dummyUserPromises];
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
}

console.log('Stop here!');
```

I'd expect all `dummyUserPromises` to be resolved when reaching the end of the code as I explicitly `await` them with `Promise.all` beforehand. When I turn on my debugger and set a breakpoint at `console.log('Stop here!')` I find that they are all still pending:

[image]

Why is this?

Comment: Because you're using square brackets instead of parentheses? Why are you doing that?

Comment: you have a typo its `all()` not `all[]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call the function:

```
 await Promise.all(dummyUserPromises)
```

Using `[]` you try to access a property of the `Promise.all` function, which will result in `undefined` and `await undefined` won't wait for anything.